# Too many active changes git warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code

i made a clean installation of visual studio code. Why do i get those warnings about Git 99+ warnings. How should i fix this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no much information in your post about the changes. Probably most of it are files that should be in the .gitingnore since those are build-product-files.

Comment: added one more pic. How do i fix this ?

Comment: @yorammi is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are Atom IDE generated files.
Add this to the `.gitignore` file:

```
.atom/
```

If the file not exists, create one in the root of the repository

Comment: where .gitignore is located ? i cant see it in Users

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you just forgot to ignore all of the generated files in your git directory. You need to find the directory and add it to your `.gitignore` file. Lets say the directory name is `node_modules`, so your .gitignore file content should be something like this

```
node_modules/
```

Using this way, those all active changes files will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

If a user sees that message it is most likely, that his **git repository root is at the different directory**, and probably is at the much higher directory (comparing to his/her repo). It can be checked by running:

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

If that's the case, then ***deleting hidden folder .git from this higher directory*** will solve the case.